# Random initial state using MultiRNNCell in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, state, recurrent-neural-network

I have a MultiRNN cell created in this way

```
def get_cell(cell_type, num_units, training):
    if cell_type == "RNN":
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units)
    elif cell_type == "LSTM":
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units)
    else:
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units)

    if training:
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell,
                                input_keep_prob=params["dropout_input_keep_prob"],
                                output_keep_prob=params["dropout_output_keep_prob"],
                                state_keep_prob=params["dropout_state_keep_prob"])

    return cell

final_cell_structure = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([get_cell(cell_type, num_units, (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)) for _ in range(num_layers)])
```

And I am trying to initialize its state to a random value. I tried doing this:

```
initial_state = state = final_cell_structure.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    state = state + tf.random_normal(shape=tf.shape(state), mean=0.0, stddev=0.6)
```

But I keep getting an error that says

```
Expected state to be a tuple of length 3, but received: Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(3, 1, 10), dtype=float32)
```

When I use it

```
output, state = final_cell_structure(inputs, state)
```

**UPDATE**
I tried using

```
state = [st + tf.random_normal(shape=tf.shape(st), mean=0.0, stddev=0.6) for st in state]
```

As suggested by Pop, and it works for Basic RNN cells and GRU cells, but when I use it with LSTM cells I get the following error

```
Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn
```

**SOLVED**
LSTM cells state is composed by a tuple, so I found this solution that works

```
state_placeholder = tf.random_normal(shape=(num_layers, 2, batch_size, num_units), mean=0.0, stddev=1.0)
l = tf.unstack(state_placeholder, axis=0)
state = tuple([tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(l[idx][0],l[idx][1]) for idx in range(num_layers)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that `state` is a tuple.

So you need to update it in this way:

```
state = [st + tf.random_normal(shape=tf.shape(st), mean=0.0, stddev=0.6) for st in state]
```

And it should work.

With your method, you were creating a single tensor f shape (2, b, k) and not a tuple of two tensors with same size (b,k)

Comment: After some tests I saw that it works for BasicRNNCell and for GRUCell, but when I use it with BasicLSTMCell I get this message: `Tensor` objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use `tf.map_fn`.